# problema en consulta anidada mysql en php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando una consulta anidada a la base de datos de la moodle, debido a que estoy trabajando con sus datos, el problema es que al realizar la consulta anidada, no me devuelve nada, nisiquiera el resultado comun que devuelven los array cuando no hay nada que es [], asi que estoy un tanto confuso, quisiera que me colaboraran para poder entender mi error.

el código es el siguiente:

el servicio.php es simplemente donde hago la conexión a la base de datos utilizando PDO, asi que dudo que el error sea de allá

```
<?php
include("servicio.php");

$id= $_REQUEST["id"];

$res = $cnx->query("SELECT c.fullname, a.name, a.intro 
FROM mdl_course AS c, mdl_assign AS a
WHERE c.id = a.course AND a.id IN(
SELECT s.assignment
FROM mdl_assign_submission AS s
WHERE a.id = s.assignment AND c.id IN(
SELECT l.courseid
FROM mdl_user_lastaccess AS l
WHERE l.courseid = c.id AND userid='$id'))");

if($res){
$datos = array();
foreach($res as $row){
    $datos[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($datos);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué no intentas con un while en vez de un foreach? así:

```
if ($res) {
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué hace $cnx->query() ? ¿hace el query y trae los datos? ¿Hace el query y te trae un resource?
prueba esto para ver que pasa:

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT c.fullname, a.name, a.intro 
FROM mdl_course AS c, mdl_assign AS a
WHERE c.id = a.course AND a.id IN(
SELECT s.assignment
FROM mdl_assign_submission AS s
WHERE a.id = s.assignment AND c.id IN(
SELECT l.courseid
FROM mdl_user_lastaccess AS l
WHERE l.courseid = c.id AND userid='$id'))";

echo $q , "\n";
$res = $cnx->query( $q );
echo '<pre>';print_r( $res );
```

**y sanitiza esto $id= $_REQUEST["id"]; para evitar SQL Injections**